# Is this Garnish message bad? "Element was added to more than one selector"

Tags: plugin-development, fieldtypes, garnish

My plugin has a field type. When I'm editing an entry which uses that field type, this message gets logged to the console:

```
Element was added to more than one selector
```

I can tell that it's Garnish which is generating this message, but **what does it mean?** Is it a problem that needs to be fixed? And if so, how would I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That message comes from from [Garnish.Select](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Garnish/blob/master/Source/classes/Select.js), when the same DOM element is associated with two separate Garnish.Select instances. The JS will log that message right before destroying the first Garnish.Select instance.

It’s not necessarily a bad thing, but could be an indication of something in your JS that could be improved. (Craft’s own JS causes several of those messages, so don’t worry too much about it if everything seems to be working correctly.)

Comment: Perfect, thanks Brandon. Then I won't worry about it too much, since everything else seems to be working normally. :)